# INT 10 to clear the screen

Tags: assembly, x86

I am sorry but I am a beginner in assembly x86 so I wonder why does the following code doesn't clear the screen

```
string              db      "Hello world",'$'
;------------------------------------------------------
                    .Code
Main                proc far
                mov ax,@data
                mov Ds,ax
                mov dx, offset string
                mov ah, 9h
                int 21h
                mov ax,0600
                mov bh,7  
                mov cx,0
                mov dx,184Fh
                int 10h
                          
Main                Endp
                    End Main
```

Comment: `mov ax,0600` should be `mov ax,0600h` (missing the `h` suffix)